# How can I Move Windows User Profiles to FBA User Profiles?

Tags: user-profile, forms-authentication

I'm working with an extranet that had been configured to use Windows Integrated Authentication in SharePoint 2010. I'd like to move it to FBA authentication, but I'm hung up on the User Profiles.
After changing the authentication model for the existing web application to FBA with the [AD provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/01/07/setting-up-fba-claims-in-sharepoint-2010-with-active-directory-membership-provider.aspx), I have a new user profile for each user.

How can I move the old user profile for the same user over to be associated with the FBA login? I don't need to maintain the old, windows style user profiles after the migration to FBA style logins.

Notes:

- I've successfully followed the instructions on [Migrate from classic-mode to claims-based authentication (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx) and that somehow matches up the windows integrated user profiles to the new windows claims user profiles. I want something like that for windows to fba.
- I've checked that the Claim User Identifier is set. Mine is set to SAMAccountName. Bryan Porter [describes Claim User Identifer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brporter/archive/2010/07/19/trusted-identity-providers-amp-user-profile-synchronization.aspx) on his blog.
- I've implemented the IMigrateUser Callback as described in [Implementing Claims-Based Authentication with SharePoint Server 2010 (whitepaper)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487289.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom, can you use powershell to read the existing (Windows) profile and then create new profiles for each FBA user with UserProfileManager.CreateUserProfile passing the claims ID.

Then copy the properties from the old profile to the new profile.

Later you can just delete the windows profiles.

Remember to test your search crawl too. You may need to set up an NTLM address for the sps3:// start address.

Comment: Hey Matt, good to see you here! I think this gets me close. The pictureurl and personal site URL properties were tripping me up for some reason I can't remember at the moment. I'll report back when I try it again.

Comment: Tom, thanks, I could see that, you may need to transform the URLs so that they work through the claims address.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to execute the Move-SPUser powershell command which replaces the old stsadm command for migrateuser.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx

This will update the user information list and maintain all user history and security including the personal MySites.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for thinking about it. Have you used Move-SPUser to update profiles from windows to fba accounts? I've tried it many ways, including with a custom IMigrateUsersCallback. I still have two profiles. I must be doing something wrong. -Tom

Comment: @TomResing It isn't going to change the profiles, you still have dupes there, and one set will need to be removed.  I've seen some scripts in the past that can redo the windows profiles to change the settings for Claims/FBA but if you already have the FBA profiles in there, then I'm not sure it is needed.

Comment: I'm confused when you say it isn't going to change the profiles. What do you mean by "This will update the profiles"?

Comment: Sorry for the slip up.  The command was built for Foundation, and doesn't take the profiles into account.  In my initial answer I meant to say User Information List, but I put profiles.  It doesn't change the profiles.  From what I understand, your users already have a Windows and a FBA profile.  This will repoint all of their site level history and security to the new FBA account.  When they log in with their FBA account, their user object should reference the FBA user profile.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I've made the same mistake a number of times over the years thinking there was some help for user profiles. I was just hoping someone would have an answer, even if it was manual instuctions for how to move the personal sites over. Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: For personal sites, the Move-SPUser should assign ownership to the FBA account.

Comment: Yes. It would appear the permissions were updated. The FBA Account is now the site collection owner, however, I receive access denied when going directly and Your personal site cannot be created when clicking "My Content" in the top nav.